# How to traceback errors in node.js when I'm running transpiled files?

Tags: node.js, babeljs, source-maps

I'm farily certain this is a very stupid question, and I'm just missing something very basic.

I currently have a node project, and I'm using babel to transpile my files into a `/dist` directory. When I start my service, I run the file that is within the `/dist` path since it contains all the nice `async/await` functionality.

However, whenever something on my server breaks locally, debugging it becomes a pain since it traces back to the file/line in the `/dist` folder which doesn't map correctly to the actual source.

i.e. : `dist/config/routeHelpers/mozApiHelper.js:187:24`

I'm using babel to transpile my files with this command:

`./node_modules/.bin/babel src -w -d dist`

Any help is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Well, for starters, you can look at the transpiled file itself at that line and column number to see what code caused the error.  You will have to manually figure out which part of the original code corresponds to that, but it's usually not that difficult.  Debuggers these days also support a .map file which will let you see the original code when stepping through the transpiled code or setting breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

To get `babel-cli` to generate source maps add the `--source-maps` argument:

```
./node_modules/.bin/babel src -w -d dist --source-maps
```

To get node to support source maps install [source-map-support](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support):

```
npm install source-map-support
```

If you were running your app with `node dist/compiled.js` before, you will now change it to:

```
node -r source-map-support/register dist/compiled.js
```

Check the source-map-support readme for other usage options.